# Script with multiple arithmetic conditions failing

Tags: bash, shell-script, arithmetic

I'm experiencing problems with a script converting numbers to bytes.

- If the number is large enough to hit gigabytes or terabytes, the
  script runs as it should.
- If the number converts to kilobytes, it runs the script, shows number
  in kilobytes and sends an error message at the same time.
- If I'm in the megabyte interval, it only sends the error message:

> line n ((: x > 1048576 : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is " "). x represents the number I input.

```
tb=1099511627776
gb=1073741824
mb=1048576
kb=1024
read number
if (( $number > $tb )); then
  echo "$(( number / tb )) terabytes"

elif (( $number > $gb )) && (( $number < $tb )); then
  echo "$(( number > gb )) gigabytes"

elif (( $number > $mb )) && (( $number < $gb )); then
  echo "$(( number > mb )) megabytes"

elif (( $number > $kb )) && (( $number < $mb )); then
  echo "$(( number > mb )) kilobytes"

fi
```

Line `n` is the middle `elif`.

Comment: Use http://www.shellcheck.net/ and add `)` in line 10.

Comment: Additionally change `echo "$(( number > gb ))` to `echo "$(( number / gb ))` == symbol `>` by `/`. More would like to test `numfmt --to=iec` command.

Comment: Finally for every `elif`, eliminate the `&&` because it's already true.

Comment: Other bug fixes include replacing `mb` with `kb` in the kilobytes case, and thinking about what happens when the input is exactly equal to one of the constants (you can get rid of about half of the comparisons), or if it is lower than `$kb`.

Comment: `t=$(((g=(m=(k=1024*(b=1))*k)*k)*k))`, you can then do the check like `for s in t g m k b; do [ "$((n>=$s))" -ne 0 ] && break; done || ! echo 0 bytes\! && echo "$((n/$s))${s#b}b"`

Answer (score 2):

There's an error in this line:   `echo "$(( number > gb ) gigabytes"` there is a missing ).

The line should read:   `echo "$(( number > gb )) gigabytes"`

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing this out, but this is an error I only made while retyping the code here, and not in my script.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem with the shellcheck checker, thanks @Cyrus. Apparently I had a non-breaking space (&nbsp) which I had to delete and make into a normal space at the middle elif between (( and $number. How does this happen?